# DRF nested serializers returns empty dictionary

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have two modals designation and UserModal

```
class DesignationModal(models.Model):
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.designation



class UserModal(AbstractUser):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    designation=models.ForeignKey(DesignationModal,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="desig",null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

every user only have one designation. I wrote serializer for that.

```
class DesignationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model=DesignationModal
        fields=['designation','id']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    designation=DesignationSerializer(read_only=True,many=False)

    class Meta:
        model=UserModal
        fields=['id', 'username','designation']
```

I'm getting a JSON response like this

```
{
"status": true,
"data": [
    
    {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "akhil",
        "designation": {}
    }
]
```

}

no values in the dictionary, when I rewrite the serializer code like this.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    designation=serializers.StringRelatedField()
    
    class Meta:
        model=UserModal
        fields=['id', 'username','designation']
```

im getting designation values as string

```
{
"status": true,
"data": [
   
    {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "akhil",
        "designation": "agent"
    }
]
```

}

why I'm not getting values in a previous way?

Answer (score 0):

Using **depth** option will get the nested values.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModal
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'designation', ]
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad inheritance for **DesignationSerializer**(serializers.Serializer) you need to change it like that

```
class DesignationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=DesignationModal
        fields=['designation','id']
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't explicitly stated in the docs, but the nested `ModelSerializer` field needs to match the `related_name` of the corresponding `ForeignKey` field in the model.

In this case `related_name="designation"` should work as expected.